# Multiple ECR20 Tokens on single Ethereum node

Tags: ethereum

Is it possible and/or recommended to use a single Ethereum node for managing multiple ecr20 tokens?

Notes:

1. I am running an EC2 Instance with 100GB of EBS (scalable). I have
   fresh installed geth.
2. I want to run multiple ECR20 Tokens such as OmiseGo and Tron and I
   want full production capabilities and reliability.

Comment: What do you mean by “run” tokens? A node holds all tokens on that blockchain. Your question doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Additionally, are you running your own private network or working with the a public one?

Comment: @AdamKipnis manage tokens, as in I want to use the node to interact (generate client addresses, send and receive tokens), my question is should I use one node to interact with multiple tokens, or should I make the nodes for each token exclusive

Comment: @Legman No, I am not

Answer (score 1):

I suppose by "running" a token you mean to interact with the ERC20 tokens by running your own RPC node.

First of all you may want to consider the EBS size as [100GB may not be enough quite soon](https://etherscan.io/chart2/chaindatasizefast)

If you want "full production capabilities and reliability" you should run several nodes. Just like all other software, Ethereum nodes can fail and the time to spin up a new node takes days, so you want to have multiple availability zones so that in case of failure you can recover within minutes/hours not days.

Comment: EBS: Yes I will scale up
Cluster Idea is good, So I will run a Cluster of nodes, but do they share the keystore?
Regardless, my question still remains, should I use one node/cluster to interact with multiple tokens, or should I make the nodes for each token exclusive.

Comment: The token contract you deploy will be on all nodes in the network. If you deploy to the public blockchain, I can start a node and execute transactions for your contract. That is the whole idea behind trustless decentralization. There is no concept of designating a node for a specific token.

Comment: @RohitHazra I think you are a bit confused here. Your keys do not need to be coupled to your geth nodes. And in most production settings, they should not be. For example [this gist](https://gist.github.com/raineorshine/c8b30db96d7532e15f85fcfe72ac719c) signs transactions on his local computer but using the public Infura node. It is a good idea to keep the "signing" node(s) separate from the "blockchain sync'ing" node(s). So if all you want is just to send transactions to your tokens, you do not need to run the nodes yourself.

Comment: But if you want "production reliability and capability" running your own "blockchain syncing" nodes is a good idea because you are not depending on a third party like Infura

Comment: @kizzx2 maybe I am confused, basically the tokens do confuse me, All I want is a functionality 

1. to create unique addresses / per token (all addresses point to a same wallet), 
2. read the deposits (via a trigger) to those addresses and 
3. send tokens from one address to another (tron to tron, omisego to omisego ...)

what I understand from your comment is that I should create the keystores on a separate node and store the private key etc.

then say using web3 I send the transactions/requests to my eth node including ecr20 contract abi as a param?